# Insert each element of a list into a separate column in mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, list

I want to be able to iterate thru a list in python and insert each element in a separate column on a table in MySQL DB.

i have this syntax which i also found here :

```
 jobdata = [sampledata,sampledata1,sampledata2]

 params = ['?' for item in jobdata]
 sql   = 'INSERT INTO refactorBatch (runnum, hold, processtn) VALUES (%s);' % ','.join(params)
 cursor.execute(sql, list)
 cnx.commit()
```

But i am having this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 355, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

Did i miss something here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it is the line

```
cursor.execute(sql, list)
```

which is attempting to use the builtin `list` type as an argument.

Comment: oh wow. thanks! got rid of the error. but another one came up @zachgates

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting